# Crystal report - print count of a record

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working on VS 2005. I am using 2 databases called student and group.

student (student_id,group_id(int))
group (group_id(int),group_name(varchar))

I have created a connection to the database.

Now I have to create the following report

Group Name                           Count
Biology                               14
Computer Science                      10

and so on

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want a report that groups by Group and counts the Students in each Group?

Insert a group in Crystal Reports on group_name.

Drag the student_id field to the Details section.

While the field is selected, right-click it and select Insert | Summary.  Choose Count, then Group #1.

Right click in the margin to the left of the Details section and choose Hide.

Run the report.

Comment: thanks a ton man...I have been looking for a solution to this problem for a long time...finally...thnx again

Answer (score 1):

Insert a summary field in the footer of each group which is a count of your primary key.